# IBM Data Studio Admin Client 3.1.1

Tags: ibm-midrange, ibm-data-studio

I have a simple IBM Data Studio issue which I can't find an answer to. I have to say the online resource and general documentation for this product is very poor.

Anyway, I have noticed in my installation that the run SQL button in the SQL editor does not have a menu containing a 'run selected' option. However in other tutorials I have seen this option does exist (and I need it).

Is this a version issue or am I missing something ? I am running the SQL on an Iseries if that makes a difference.

Comment: The current version of Data Studio is 4.1.1  Are you sure the tutorials you're looking at are for the older 3.1.1?

Comment: do you have something selected the button may be dynamic

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think I have the latest version of the Admin client (which is 3.1.1). The tutorial I was looking at was from 2009 so not a version issue I don't think. I suspect it is to do with the as400 toolbox driver. I'll try connecting to something else and see what happens.

Comment: I know run selected was available back in ot nine?

Comment: Maybe the button is dynamic and you need to actually have some text selected?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Data Studio (at the time of writing) is 4.1.3 APAR2

APAR fixes can be downloaded here https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Information+Management&product=ibm/Information+Management/IBM+Data+Studio&platform=All&function=all
and can be applied on-top of the full install

Download Data Studio from here https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/index.html  or here https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/ibm-data-studio

Knowledge Center docs are here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS62YD_4.1.1/com.ibm.datatools.ds.nav.doc/topics/ds_landing.html

If you have any installation issues, this doc can useful http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037681